# Sed search and replace syntax in Cygwin?

Tags: sed, cygwin

I am trying to serch and replace using sed in Cygwin:

```
SRC_FOLDER_MAIN=bra
TGT_FOLDER_MAIN=tag
```

but the following sed command does not work:

```
sed 's/${SRC_FOLDER_MAIN}/${TGT_FOLDER_MAIN}/g' externals.txt > externals_mod.txt
```

This for example works OK (replaces "bra" with "tag"):

```
sed 's/bra/tag/g' externals.txt > externals_mod.txt
```

What am I missing?

Could it be that Cygwin is the problem?

Comment: +1 for your example, it maybe a typo, however make sense! same as `<tag>`, **`bra`** must be **paired** too ^_^.

Comment: Paired? I did not understand...?

Comment: it's an extremely difficult concept requiring years of intense study :P :P :P

Comment: ah ok, I see... will get down to business.

Comment: ...... just forget it if you didn't get it...

Comment: it's native eng speaker thing right... definitely paired if possible :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to pass shell variables in sed, you need to take them out of the single quote
try like this

`sed 's/'${SRC_FOLDER_MAIN}'/'${TGT_FOLDER_MAIN}'/g' $externals.txt > $externals_mod.txt`

notice the `'` just before and after `${SRC_FOLDER_MAIN}` and similar in `${TGT_FOLDER_MAIN}`

Update: Example

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
we will replace aaaa with bbbb
[[bash_prompt$]]$ a=aaaa;b=bbbb
[[bash_prompt$]]$ sed 's/'${a}'/'${b}'/g' log > new_log
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat new_log
we will replace bbbb with bbbb
```

Comment: probably, in that case, i'm not the right person. Better add cygwin also in your question tag

Answer (score 3):

To make `sed` replace based on variables value, wrap it with double quotes and use simple variable calling, without `{}`. Also, is `$externals*.txt` correct? If you are calling files, just put their name.

```
sed "s/$SRC_FOLDER_MAIN/$TGT_FOLDER_MAIN/g" $externals.txt > $externals_mod.txt
```

Instead of

```
sed 's/${SRC_FOLDER_MAIN}/${TGT_FOLDER_MAIN}/g' $externals.txt > $externals_mod.txt
```

Comment: Double quotes don't work: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Uhms I see, try with `sed "s/$SRC_FOLDER_MAIN/$TGT_FOLDER_MAIN/g" $externals.txt > $externals_mod.txt` as updated. That is, without `{}` for variables.

Comment: Again error: sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Post the exact command you are using. I am not adding any `-e` nor `-s`.

Comment: @Danijel sed is very sensitive in terms of what it will allow in the search/replace areas, but the text you posted should not produce the error you're seeing. Modify your question with a copy/paste of your window to show you populating your variables, running sed, and the output you get so we can see what you're REALLY doing.

Comment: Now I see the file names were called with `$externals.txt`. If this is not a variable but a file name, just put `externals.txt` as indicated on my updated answer.

Comment: @fedorqui - the OP said the hard-coded sed worked with those file names so they must be fine as-is.

Comment: Oh, I see @EdMorton. Updated answer mentioning it. Thanks!

Comment: I did not add any -e, the line is as above. I have no idea why this error is reported even there are no switches whatsoever.

Comment: So basic `sed "s/${SRC_FOLDER_MAIN}/${TGT_FOLDER_MAIN}/g" externals.txt > externals_mod.txt` should work. At least it does to me.

Comment: Ahhh why it doesn't for me? Still sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running this script in cygwin. Does that matter?

Comment: It may matter, I don't know. Check `man sed` to see if you can find some hints. I reached my limit : )

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the standard Windows cmd shell?

If so then you need to wrap environment variables in % signs, like so:

```
sed 's/%SRC_FOLDER_MAIN%/%TGT_FOLDER_MAIN%/g' externals.txt > externals_mod.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling with the characters sed will accept in it's substitution, just use awk:

```
SRC_FOLDER_MAIN=bra
TGT_FOLDER_MAIN=tag

awk -v src="$SRC_FOLDER_MAIN" -v tgt="$TGT_FOLDER_MAIN" '{gsub(src,tgt)}1' "$externals.txt" > "$externals_mod.txt"
```

That will work with any characters in the variables. The only thing to be aware of is that, like with sed, the "source" will be treated as a regexp so RE metacharacters (e.g. "." or "*") will be meaningful - if that's an issue, let us know as there is a simple awk solution but no equivalent sed solution.

awk for finding and replacing a string rather than a regexp:

```
awk -v src="$SRC_FOLDER_MAIN" -v tgt="$TGT_FOLDER_MAIN" '
    idx = index($0,src) { $0 = substr($0,1,idx-1) tgt substr($0,idx+length(src)) }1
' "$externals.txt" > "$externals_mod.txt"
```